# a correct way to programming NSOperation subclass cancel

Tags: cocoa, concurrency

Hi
i'm using mysql connection from 5.5. version mysqllibclient.
Is it a way to make something, to stop mysql query if i seen that isCancelled is start to yes?
Timers doesn't work stable in nsoperation, i don't know why (please see my question about nstimer problem, it is not answered).

Answer (score 1):

```
// you have two immediate options:

// 1) override cancel:
- (void)cancel {
    [super cancel];
    /* get out */
}

// 2) test isCancelled
- (void)main {
    /* ... */
    if (self.isCancelled) {
      /* get out */
    }
    else {
      /* continue working */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for. When libmysqlclient receive query, i don't have control it from my code. This is a problem, which have to be solved. If i will override cancel, it will be cancelled and libmysqlclient will close connection?

Comment: @Alex ah, sorry for misunderstanding your problem. perhaps you should create another question with more detail and code examples.